# Do characters use my guns/ammo if equipped when I am not controlling them?

Tags: state-of-decay

If some of my playable characters have guns or ammo on them, will they use these items when I am not controlling them, for example on a supply run or when a horde attacks base? I don't think I have seen it happen, just melee fighting. Also, can characters take weapons or supplies from locker without my control (and lose them)?

Answer (score 2):

Actually they do take stuff from your locker. I went out and found a lot of nice guns, only to get on the next day to see that a lot of them were missing and my survivors were equipped with them.

Answer (score 0):

If a character is out on a mission with you. For example zed hunts. They will you use the weapon you last used with that character. For example I used a machete with one character instead of his frying pan. When I switched characters and a zed hunt mission popped up. That character used the machete. While I used my weapon.

Comment: As far as guns I haven't seen it yet. But I would figure they do. Maybe if there on guard duty. Or if they don't have a melee weapon.

Answer (score 0):

For the guns, I would have to say that NPCs no longer under your control do not use up the ammo that you have given them when you were in control of them. They also do not use or take any thing from the supply locker.